# Retrieving several capturing groups recursively with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion

I have a string with this format:

```
#someID@tn@company@somethingNew@classing@somethingElse@With
```

There might be unlimited @-separated words, but definitely the whole string begins with #

I have written the following regexp, though it matches it, but I cannot get each @-separated word, and what I get is the last recursion and the first (as well as the whole string). How can I get an array of every word in an element separately?

```
(?:^\#\w*)(?:(\@\w*)+) //I know I have ruled out second capturing group with ?: , though doesn't make much difference.
```

And here is my Javascript code:

```
var reg = /(?:^\#\w*)(?:(\@\w*)+)/g;

var x = null;


while(x = reg.exec("#someID@tn@company@somethingNew@classing@somethingElse@With"))
{
  console.log(x); 
}
```

And here is the result (Firebug, console):

```
["#someID@tn@company@somet...sing@somethingElse@With", "@With"]


0
    "#someID@tn@company@somet...sing@somethingElse@With"

1
    "@With"

index
    0

input
    "#someID@tn@company@somet...sing@somethingElse@With"
```

**EDIT** : 
I want an output like this with regular expression if possible:

```
["#someID", "@tn", @company", "@somethingNew", "@classing", "@somethingElse", "@With"]
```

NOTE that I want a RegExp solution. I know about String.split() and String operations.

Comment: What is the expected output in this case?

Comment: Are you sure `["#someID", "@tn@company", "@somethingNew", "@classing", "@somethingElse", "@With"]` is the output that you expect, and not `["#someID", "@tn", "@company", "@somethingNew", "@classing", "@somethingElse", "@With"]`

Comment: @user3853834 you mean this http://regex101.com/r/zX5dJ7/6

Comment: @chris97on You are right

Comment: @AvinashRaj please post it as an answer and explain it if possible, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this regex also,

```
((?:@|#)\w+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zX5dJ7/6)

**Explanation:**

- `()` Capturing groups. Anything inside this capturing group would be captured.
- `(?:)` It just matches the strings but won't capture anything.
- `@|#` Literal `@` or `#` symbol.
- `\w+` Followed by one or more word characters.

**OR**

```
> "#someID@tn@company@somethingNew@classing@somethingElse@With".split(/\b(?=@|#)/g);
[ '#someID',
  '@tn',
  '@company',
  '@somethingNew',
  '@classing',
  '@somethingElse',
  '@With' ]
```

Comment: Won't this also match `someID@email.com` where `#` as first character is missing?

Comment: @anubhava http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884641/retrieving-several-capturing-groups-recursively-with-regexp/24884846#comment38652874_24884641

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your comment. You link is just going back to this thread.

Comment: op ask me post this as an answer.

Comment: Yes that I have read. I am just pointing out issues with this approach to OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var s = '#someID@tn@company@somethingNew@classing@somethingElse@With'
if (s.substr(0, 1) == "#")
    tok = s.substr(1).split('@');    
    //=> ["someID", "tn", "company", "somethingNew", "classing", "somethingElse", "With"]
```

Comment: I know, I need regExp

Comment: Thanks @zx81. user3853834: `String#split` uses `regex` to split. One should not complicate the solution if it can be solved with less complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier without regExp:

```
var str = "#someID@tn@company@somethingNew@classing@somethingElse@With";
var strSplit = str.split("@");
for(var i = 1; i < strSplit.length; i++) {
    strSplit[i] = "@" + strSplit[i];
}
console.log(strSplit);
// ["#someID", "@tn", "@company", "@somethingNew", "@classing", "@somethingElse", "@With"]
```